# How to get the text

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I have some html to scrape.

```
<div class="content">
  <strong> This is first content </strong> This is second content
  <br />
  <small>
    <p>Something</p>
  </small>
</div>
```

how to get the **This is second content** with **cheerio** ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it with cheerio, but please look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/vsqb0gy6/ using only javascript, it could give you an idea of how to do it with cheerio

Comment: The idea is to obtain all the child nodes of the container, including text type, then filter to list only those of the text type, then transform each node using the trim method that eliminates the spaces and `\n` to finally filter on the text that has some content.

I am not familiar with cheerio but it seems to share similar api with jQuery, if so the examples at https://api.jquery.com/contents/ will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `nodeType` property, it could solve your problem even if you have text before `<strong>` tag

```
<div class="content">
  Before first content
  <strong> This is first content </strong> This is second content
  <br />
  <small>
    <p>Something</p>
  </small>
</div>
```

Then it could be

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio")
const $ = cheerio.load('<div class="content">Before first content<strong> This is first content </strong> This is second content<br /><small><p>Something</p></small></div>');

var $outer = $("div.content").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});

console.log($outer.text()); //"Before first content This is second content"

$outer.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
//"Before first content"
//" This is second content"
```

Check it [here](https://runkit.com/embed/35l5gbup4uow)

Comment: How to remove **\n** , **\t** , and **(long space)** . i've use ```.trim()``` but the **\n** and others doesn't removed

Comment: Basically `.trim()` does it good in this case (beginning and ending), what html that you encountered?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly select text nodes. I usually do something like:

```
$('.content strong')[0].nextSibling.data
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
<div class="content">
  <strong> This is first content </strong> <span class="toBeSelected">This is second content</span>
  <br />
  <small>
    <p>Something</p>
  </small>
</div>
```

After this you can select the text this way.

```
$('div .toBeSelected').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should put the 'This is a second content' in span or something else to specify properly to get its content.

do this:

```
<div class="content">
 <strong>This is first content</strong><span>This is second content</span>
<br>
  <small>
    <p>Something</p>
  </small>
</div>
```

Get it like this

```
console.log($('.content :nth-child(2)').text())
```

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/vg1dqm3L/17/ for you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use regex to get the second content.

```
    const cheerio = require('cheerio');
    const $ = cheerio.load(`<div class="content">
    <strong> This is first content </strong> This is second content

    <br />
    <small>
    <p> Something </p>
    </small>
    </div>
    `);
    console.log($('div').html().replace(/\n/g, '').match(/<\/strong>(.*)<br>/)[1])
```

Comment: This does not match the content as provided by OP.